# How I guarantee I create only one new unique node between two existing nodes in a transaction

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have the following 2 existing nodes in my graph.

A **Customer** node identified by a unique customer number.
A **Product** node identified by a unique ISBN identifier.

I want to create an association between one **Customer** node and one **Product** node.
But I want to represent this association as a new node called a **License** node which will have one link to the **Customer** node and one link to the **Product** node.

This **License** node will have a new internal identifier generated as a random GUID.

My logic in my application which creates the new **License** node and links them to the other 2 nodes is executed in one transaction.

`if (Product NOT already associated with the License for that Customer) 
    create a new License node with a new random GUID
    create a relationship from the new License Node to the Product Node
    create a relationship from the Customer Node to the new License Node`

However multiple requests can arrive at the same time with the same ISBN and customer number.
When this happens I am sometimes getting duplicate **License** nodes created for the same **Customer** and **Product** nodes.
The transaction in spring data neo4j does not seem to prevent this from happening.

[Example of correctly added License](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2RmT.jpg)

[Example of License added twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L4aE.jpg)

How can I ensure that only one License node will get created between the Customer node and the Product node?

Comment: How looks like the Cypher query you are using to execute the logic?

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I am using Java 1.8 and Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0 and the cypher gets generated by the framework. The transaction is also defined as an annotation.
I will try out the suggestions made by frant.hartm in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The transaction in spring data neo4j does not seem to prevent this from happening.

Neo4j has *read commited* isolation level for transactions. To prevent this you would need *serializable*.

To achieve what you need you could:

- lock Product and Customer node before doing the `Product NOT already associated with...` check. You could use a query like this to do that (within the same transaction):

  ```
  MATCH (n:Product) WHERE ID(n) = {id} REMOVE n._lock
  ```

  and similar for `Customer`.
- add a special key to License which is a concatenation of Product and Customer ids - then create a unique constraint on that.

Comment: Thanks Frant. I took the first approach and this has worked for me.
Using `MATCH (p:Product) WHERE ID(p) = {id} SET p._lock = 1` at the start of the transaction and `MATCH (p:Product) WHERE ID(p) = {id} REMOVE p._lock` at the end of the transaction.

Comment: The `REMOVE n._lock` at the _start_ of the transaction should work as well and will save you one query at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Yep, That worked too. I think I understand, because removing the property ensures a write lock is taken on the node.
http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-locking
`When adding, changing or removing a property on a node or relationship a write lock will be taken on the specific node or relationship.`

Comment: I have noticed after further testing that I can now reconstruct a test where only removing the property with the one call doesn't work.
However setting the property before the check and then removing the property at the end of the tx code has worked for all my tests (I can never test this 100%).
I am wondering if Neo4j maybe doesn't take the write lock on the node if it detects that you are trying to remove a property that doesn't exist and maybe in earlier versions it may have been doing that?

Comment: @DonalHurley what version of Neoj4 is that? Could you share the test case?

Comment: We are using this version of Neo4j `neo4j-enterprise-3.1.1-unix.tar.gz`. There are 5 concurrent threads in a spring boot application trying to create the one *License* node for the same *Customer* and *Product* node and arriving at the same time. I'm using  `<neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.1</neo4j-ogm.version>`and `<neo4j.version>3.2.2</neo4j.version>` libraries using a Repository class for each node and `@Transactional` to bind the logic in a Tx for the method. Then added named cypher queries in the repositories for the setting and removing of the 'fake' property.

Comment: I created a demo project in github which reconstructs my problem in a test see https://github.com/donalthurley/neo4j-locks-test. 
I also started looking at the documentation for Neo4j 3.2 (we're only using 3.1) and I think it is recommending setting and removing the property under this section http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#_lost_updates_in_cypher for a similar scenario.

Comment: @DonalHurley There is a typo at this line https://github.com/donalthurley/neo4j-locks-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/repository/CustomerRepository.java#L19

Comment: I corrected the typo. After doing that I am still seeing the same problem when I call the implementation that only removes the property. My suspicion is that this behaviour may not be supported now and that you need to do a set and then remove. This implementation is working for my test.